# Determining the position of pixel to stop changing the color

Tags: c#, image-processing

[image: Picture of a brain]

In the given image of a brain, there are two sides left and right of the brain.

I need to change the color of the right side. To access each pixel I am using the code given below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.Width; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.Height; j++) {
   actualColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
  }
}
```

How can I change the pixel color of only one side of brain(left or right)?
What should be the condition on which I should change the color?

The picture may change also where oly small portion of one part(left or right) is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Im fairly sure this is totally obvious and so kinda useless to you but assuming the picture is symmetric (its not) or symmetric enough, a sloppy approximation would be to just iterate over each pixel in image and get the bounds of the part which has the brain, i.e.

```
//if image height = ih and image width = iw

//iterate from the left
int beginX=0;
for(int x=0;x<iw;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<ih;y++){
        if(image.getPixelColor!=black){
            beginX=x;
        }
    }
}



//iterate from the right
int endX=0;
for(int x=iw;x<1;x--){
    for(int y=0;y<ih;y++){
        if(image.getPixelColor!=black){
            endX=x;
        }
    }
}

int midPointX=(endX+beginX)/2
```

so your condition would then be:

for the left part -->if x in the range (beginX,midPointX)

for the right part -->if x in the range (midPointX,endX)

Comment: But if the picture changes where only one part is visible then this will not work